# NHibernate and Raw ADO.NET usage

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net

Background: I am using Nhibernate in an ASP.NET MVC application with an open-session-in-view pattern and I need to use raw ADO.NET to execute some performance-critical database operations.

I'm somewhat confused about how I should be getting my connection instance as I've seen two different methods in numerous blog posts.

Do I want to use:

```
var connection = Session.Connection;
```

Or:

```
var connection = ((ISessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory).ConnectionProvider.GetConnection();
```

I can't seem to find a conclusive answer anywhere and I'm hoping that someone with some extensive NHibernate experience can chime in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a session, use the connection from it.

That will also allow you to share the transaction (if one is open) by enlisting your commands on it.

Comment: Is it possible to use an entirely different transaction using this connection without involving NHibernate at all? Ideally I'd like to use a READ UNCOMMITTED isolalation level because the read operation is rather performance-sensitive.

Comment: @DanP If you don't want to share anything with NH, why reference it at all? You can just use the same connection string... In any case, you *can* specify `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` when beginning an NH transaction too...

Answer (score 2):

i'm using something in the lines of (also uses the underlying already-open transaction)

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateString, (SqlConnection)NHibernateSession.Connection);
command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());

try
{
    ITransaction tx = NHibernateSession.Transaction;
    tx.Enlist(command);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException)
{
    NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.RollbackTransaction();
    throw;
}
```